# Response from Python requests to a file(Data Format Issue/Question)

Tags: python, api

This is the python script, which im using to call an api and get the data into a file.

```
import requests

url = "XXXX"

payload = {}
headers= {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
response.raise_for_status()
file = open("/u/users/xxxxx/Offers.csv", "w")
file.write(response.text.encode('utf8'))
file.close()
```

The data is coming to the file in below format

```
[{"Id":"XXXXXX","Name":"XXXX"}]
```

But I need the data in the below format

```
Id        Name
XXX       XXXXX
```

I want to use this data to load again into a table. Also, I want to implement error handling and setup an e-mail confirmation check if something happens to the job when it completes/fails.Can someone help how to acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas to achieve this:

```
import pandas as pd

x = [{"Id":"XXXXXX","Name":"XXXX"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
csv_data = df.to_csv('mycsv.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: How do i define x = [{"Id":"XXXXXX","Name":"XXXX"}] ? The data is huge and i will be scheduling the script to run on a daily basis.

Comment: i got this, when i ran the script "ImportError: No module named pandas"

Comment: You should install Pandas first `pip install pandas`